# ASP.NET SignalR undefined hub error

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am working on a custom action for our company's shopping cart website.  It is a software that is installed and setup, and we are able to add to it by creating custom actions.  I created an ASP.NET (web forms) page that uses SignalR to add to it, but whenever it tries to grab an instance of the hub within javascript, it is always undefined.

In Chrome, I can see signalr/hubs, and there are no 404 not found errors on the page either.  It works perfectly fine when running it in debug from VS 2012, but not from within the web site on the server.

I am certain I have deployed all the necessary components, and have tried many approaches to changing the way it finds the hub, but nothing seems to work.
I can provide code samples if needed.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.  It was related to the name of the hub being misspelled in javascript.  Once that got fixed, then the function name needed to be changed in javascript so the first character is lowercase.  It is working as intended now.

Comment: How was anyone else supposed to arrive at this conclusion when you didn't include the code in your question?

Comment: No need to include code. Just follow instructions easily found online. I had made the mistake of misspelling the hub name, and thus was not able to get it to work.
For reference, here is the link to a codeproject page I used to get it working for me: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/722331/ProgressBar-using-JQueryUI-and-SignalR